# Persistent ESTABLISHED State Connections in Conntrack Table in HWOL Environment Post Load Testing

Tags: networking, 22.04

I’ve been conducting load tests in a Hardware Offload (HWOL) Conntrack environment and have encountered an issue where, post-testing, all connections on the VM have terminated but the conntrack table still retains flows in the ESTABLISHED state.

Here’s a snippet of the conntrack table:

```
root@test02:/# conntrack -L | grep ESTA | head -n 10
tcp      6 85390 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.115 dst=10.168.66.221 sport=9172 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.221 dst=10.168.68.115 sport=8080 dport=9172 [ASSURED] zone=15 use=1
tcp      6 86092 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.118 dst=10.168.66.14 sport=35885 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.14 dst=10.168.68.118 sport=8080 dport=35885 [ASSURED] zone=2 use=1
tcp      6 85561 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.218 dst=10.168.66.221 sport=24124 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.221 dst=10.168.68.218 sport=8080 dport=24124 [ASSURED] zone=15 use=1
tcp      6 85721 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.153 dst=10.168.66.151 sport=40994 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.151 dst=10.168.68.153 sport=8080 dport=40994 [ASSURED] zone=13 use=1
tcp      6 85879 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.148 dst=10.168.66.151 sport=60456 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.151 dst=10.168.68.148 sport=8080 dport=60456 [ASSURED] zone=13 use=1
tcp      6 85397 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.143 dst=10.168.66.252 sport=8089 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.252 dst=10.168.68.143 sport=8080 dport=8089 [ASSURED] zone=11 use=1
tcp      6 85687 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.195 dst=10.168.66.19 sport=5139 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.19 dst=10.168.68.195 sport=8080 dport=5139 [ASSURED] zone=8 use=1
tcp      6 85786 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.170 dst=10.168.66.223 sport=36659 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.223 dst=10.168.68.170 sport=8080 dport=36659 [ASSURED] zone=12 use=1
tcp      6 85591 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.150 dst=10.168.66.204 sport=45455 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.204 dst=10.168.68.150 sport=8080 dport=45455 [ASSURED] zone=7 use=1
tcp      6 86087 ESTABLISHED src=10.168.68.215 dst=10.168.66.97 sport=14570 dport=8080 src=10.168.66.97 dst=10.168.68.215 sport=8080 dport=14570 [ASSURED] zone=6 use=1
```

```
root@test02:/# conntrack -L | grep -v HW_OFF | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq -c                                                                                                                                                                                                          
conntrack v1.4.6 (conntrack-tools): 103694 flow entries have been shown.
      2 CLOSE_WAIT
 103589 ESTABLISHED
      2 src=10.168.66.151
      2 src=10.168.66.204
      1 src=10.168.66.221
      1 src=10.168.66.252
      2 src=10.168.66.97
     58 SYN_SENT
     17 TIME_WAIT
```

The current netfilter conntrack table size is set to 1048576 and during the load test, the conntrack table size did not exceed 800K.

Here are the details of my setup:

**Hardware**

- Server: Dell R7615
- CPU: AMD Epyc 9654P
- Memory: 384GB
- NUMA: 1
- NIC: Connect-X 6LX

**Software Versions**

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Kernel: 5.15
- Openstack Version: Yoga
- OVN: 22.03
- OVS: 2.17.5
- MLNX OFED Driver: 5.8-2.0.3
- Firmware: 26.35.1012 (DEL0000000031)

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.